# Setting label on Google Compute Engine instance disk

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm going to try to set a disk label on a Google Compute Engine instance. Basically what is documentated here:

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/disks/setLabels

Unfortunately also using the simple code provided by Google:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('Google-ComputeSample/0.1');
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
$client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform');
$service = new Google_Service_Compute($client);
$project = 'my-project';
$zone = 'my-zone';
$resource = 'my-resource';  // here i set the disk name
$requestBody = new Google_Service_Compute_ZoneSetLabelsRequest();
$response = $service->disks->setLabels($project, $zone, $resource, $requestBody);
echo '<pre>', var_export($response, true), '</pre>', "\n";
?>
```

I always hit a 500 error:

> Uncaught Google_Service_Exception: { "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "conditionNotMet", "message": "Labels fingerprint either invalid or resource labels have changed", "locationType": "header", "location": "If-Match" } ], "code": 412, "message": "Labels fingerprint either invalid or resource labels have changed" } }

where I suppose that I have the wrong label syntax. But in the label method, I have tried several syntax:

```
$requestBody->setLabels(array("mylabel"=>"1"));
$requestBody->setLabels(serialize(array("mylabel"=>"1")));
$requestBody->setLabels('"mylabel":"1"');
$requestBody->setLabels('{"mylabel":"1"}');
```

but none work. And nothing has changed (always 500 error with the same exception). What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error response you're receiving indicates that the labelFingerprint is wrong or not set. The request body should contain both the labels and the labelFingerprint and it looks like you're only setting the former:

```
{
  "labels": {
    string: string,
    ...
  },
  "labelFingerprint": string
}
```

The documentation you linked explains what the lableFingerprint is:

> The fingerprint of the previous set of labels for this resource, used to detect conflicts. The fingerprint is initially generated by Compute Engine and changes after every request to modify or update labels. You must always provide an up-to-date fingerprint hash in order to update or change labels. Make a get() request to the resource to get the latest fingerprint.
>
> A base64-encoded string.

Comment: thank you for your feedback. You get me in the right direction to solve the problem.

Comment: That's great, glad I could help. You can accept the answer if you like!

Comment: sure. sorry i have forgot to do it before!